# local variable 'template' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have model called template in my models.py file

```
class template(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False,null=False)
    data = RichTextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("templatedetail",kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Then i'm importing this model in my views.py

```
from .models import template
```

Then when i try to get all objects in a method

```
def assign_user_template(request,email=None):
    if 'credentials' not in request.session:
        return redirect('/oauth2callback/')

    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(request.session['credentials'])
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return redirect('/oauth2callback/')
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        user_service = build('admin','directory_v1',http=http)
        user_profile = user_service.users().get(userKey=email).execute()
        user_profile_email = user_profile.get('primaryEmail')
        user_profile_service = build('oauth2', 'v2', http=http)
        user_info = user_profile_service.userinfo().get().execute()
        user_email = user_info.get('email')
        admin_service = build('admin','directory_v1',http=http)
        admin_profile = admin_service.users().get(userKey=user_email).execute()
        customer_id = admin_profile.get('customerId')
        templates = template.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id)
        template_user_object = template_user_map.objects.filter(user_email = email)
        if template_user_object:
            template_user_object = template_user_map.objects.get(user_email = email)
            template_user = template_user_object.template_id            
        else:
            template_user = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TemplateSelectForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                template = form.cleaned_data['selected_template']
                user_template_map_object = template_user_map(user_email=user_profile_email,template_id=template)
                user_template_map_object.save()
                user_profile = user_service.users().get(userKey=user_profile_email).execute()
                customer_id = user_profile.get('customerId')
                customer_object = customer.objects.get(id = customer_id)
                //some code
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/userlist/')
        else:
            form = TemplateSelectForm()
        return render(request,'assign_user_template.html',{"form":form})
```

but i'm getting this local variable 'template' referenced before assignment error. the model is imported in a correct way. when i try this on a different model it is not giving any error.

full traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (6)\final\lib\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (6)\final\lib\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (6)\final\lib\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (6)\final\dashboard\views.py" in assign_user_template
  675.         templates = template.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /edituser/bravin@demo.fcpl.biz/assigntemplate/
Exception Value: local variable 'template' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Change the model name to Template from template. Migrate and check

Comment: This method have a lot of code inside. i don't think it's better to put all the codes here but i have another model called customers but when i try to load all the customer objects its working perfectly

Comment: Impossible to answer without the full code. Please put code here.

Comment: Not aware of models.Model but do you need to create object of template before you access template.objects.all() ?

Comment: more code has been added as per request

Comment: @Bravin can you add the stacktrace please?

Comment: @ruddra traceback has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 template = form.cleaned_data['selected_template']
```

I think its the name collides with the class template. Cap all your classes.

Comment: That was the exact problem. after i changed the name now its working. Thank you